# Using ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory and ExtractTofile

Tags: c#, zip

I have a zip file which contains another zip file inside and a few other files.

I pick up the main file and I can unzip it into a destination using ExtractToDirectory. This works OK and I end up with a zip file and a few other XML files.

Next I look through the files I just extracted and pick up the .zip file name. If I now use ExtractToDirectory then I get a problem as it will not overwrite the files in the root with ones from this zip.

I find I can force overwrite if I use ExtractTofile but I need to work out the directory. I thought I was but as much as I try I get issues with the code extracting this second zip.

Any ides how to extract this second file and overwrite the existing files?

```
 ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(file_name, destination);

 var d = new DirectoryInfo(destination);
 FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*.zip"); //Get name of zip files

 foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
 {
     //open file
     ZipArchive zipArchive = ZipFile.OpenRead(destination + "\\"+ file);

     foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in zipArchive.Entries)
     {
         //If Dir does not exist then make it
         if (!Directory.Exists(destination + entry.FullName))
         Directory.CreateDirectory(destination + entry.FullName);

         // extract files into that folder
         entry.ExtractToFile(destination + entry.FullName, true);

         // Show user what you are doing             
         rchtxtbx_output.AppendText("Extracting ..... " + entry.FullName + "\r");
         rchtxtbx_output.ScrollToCaret();
      }
      zipArchive.Dispose();
 }
```

Comment: what issues ? once you use `ZipFile.OpenRead(destination + "\\"+ file);` - once you use `destination + entry.FullName`   .. printout the values you use there and post them here as well please.

Comment: destination = F:

Comment: file = first.zip  entry.Fullname = path inside second.zip

Comment: Use a breakpoint, Inspect the values. What is the result of `destination + entry.FullName` and what _exactly_ is your error message.if you have questions provide 
your code as [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you encounter errors, copy and paste
the error message verbatim ( word for word) into your question. Avoid using screenshots unless you 
need to convey layout errors. We can NOT copy and paste your image into our IDEs to fix your code.

Answer (score 0):

After a while I worked out what is wrong. For me I was getting .Name and .FullName giving me the same result. Now I get the .FullName and manually strip it so I can extract the directory that I need to make. Suddenly it all works. Fixed code I am using is below.

```
                //If archive directory exists then delete it.
                if (Directory.Exists(destination + "archive")) Directory.Delete(destination + "archive", true);
                ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(file_name, temp_destination);


                //look inside that folder for another zip file containing the data we need
                var d = new DirectoryInfo(temp_destination);
                FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*.zip"); //Get txt files

                foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
                {


                    new Thread(() =>
                    {
                        Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true;

                        ZipArchive zipArchive = ZipFile.OpenRead(temp_destination + file.Name);

                        foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in zipArchive.Entries)
                        {
                            string completeFileName = entry.FullName;
                            int idx = completeFileName.LastIndexOf('/');


                            if (completeFileName.Contains('/'))
                            {
                                string foldername = completeFileName.Substring(0, idx);


                                if (!Directory.Exists(destination + foldername))
                                    Directory.CreateDirectory(destination + foldername);
                            }

                            entry.ExtractToFile(Path.Combine(destination, entry.FullName), true);
                            Invoke(new Action(() =>
                            {
                                rchtxtbx_output.AppendText("Extracting .....  " + entry.FullName);
                                rchtxtbx_output.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
                                rchtxtbx_output.ScrollToCaret();
                                Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
                            }));


                        }


                        zipArchive.Dispose();
```